# mysql sum column between dates by users

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to sum all the times(timers.date_time with Date_time format) in a table by users that belong to the same project, within the last 7 days and show users that have not do any work as 00:00:00 format.

**Timers  table**

```
Name          Type     
timer_id     int(11)
user_id      int(5)
user_name    varchar(250) 
Proj_id      Int(10)
Proj_name    varchar(250
workingOn    text
date_time    datetime
```

**Login table**

```
Name        Type

id_login   int(11)
name_login varchar(45)
username   varchar(100)
password   varchar(18)
useremail  varchar(45)
tel_number varchar(12)
type_login int(5)
```

My last go is as follows,

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(SELECT timers.user_name,timers.workingOn,Date_Format(timers.date_time, 
       '%d/%m/%Y') AS DDAte,Time_Format(timers.date_time, '%H:%i:%s') AS Duration 

FROM timers 

WHERE DATE(timers.date_time) > (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND
Proj_name= 'Project 1' 
ORDER BY timer_id DESC) AS x 
GROUP BY user_name
```

The above query does not sum the timers.date_time column propery
and is missing users that have not worked in the last 7 Days (as User name and 00:00:00)

I Have been trying for the last 4 days with no luck, Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sample data would really help.  I don't get how the same column has both duration information that can be summed and the date.

Answer (score 0):

You could  use time_to_sec for converting the time in seconds  and sum(  sec_to_time) for get a valida time result

in this sample group by x.user_name, x.workingOn, x.DDAte

```
  SELECT x.user_name, x.workingOn, x.DDAte, SEC_TO_TIME(sum( x.duration))
  FROM 
  ( SELECT timers.user_name,timers.workingOn,Date_Format(timers.date_time, 
         '%d/%m/%Y') AS DDAte, TIME_TO_SEC( timers.date_time )  AS Duration 

  FROM timers 

  WHERE DATE(timers.date_time) > (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND
  Proj_name= 'Project 1' 
  ORDER BY timer_id DESC) AS x 
  GROUP BY user_name, x.workingOn, x.DDAte
```

Comment: Worked but Outputs all record for the last 7 days

Comment: My query is, what is the total time that user A has done in the last 7 days  (project 1) and user b, etc with each user have one row returned with their name and duration and if possible user in the project with no work done in the last 7 Days.  Hope this explains it better.

Answer (score 0):

If I assume that the "date/time" is really "date/duration", then here is one method:

```
SELECT t.user_name, t.workingOn,
       COALESCE(SEC_TO_TIME(seconds), '0:00:00')
FROM (SELECT t.user_name, t.workingOn, 
             SUM(CASE WHEN t.date_time >= curdate() -
 interval 7 day)
                      THEN time_to_sec(time(date_time))
                 END) as seconds 
      FROM timers t
      WHERE Proj_name = 'Project 1' 
      GROUP BY t.user_name, t.workingOn
     ) t
```

You can actually do this without the subquery, but I figure breaking up the logic makes it simpler to follow.

Comment: An example without a sub query would help me to understand.

Comment: Did not work. I think my version of mysql (phpMyAdmin 4.2.10) is to old for "COALESCE"